# Numerous buttons in a view

Tags: uiview, uibutton

I want to create 25 buttons in my view. Should I create 25 buttons(UIbutton butonwithtype) individually or is there any other alternative ? Please comment if the Question is not understood by you.

Answer (score 0):

I've been creating an app with a UIView that contains around 20 buttons as well. In a for-loop i've created each button individually, because each button has another frame and function. So, there's no other way for you to build each single UIButton. Have a look at the memory management.

Comment: Hai burki,    
Why to have a look at memory management ? I cannot understand the purpose of ur last suggestion. and ya thanks for your answer.